# Host is unreachable (Host unreachable)] on Rest Template

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I am using rest template to send a http request to external resource, named as *abc.xyz:12345* but i am unable to send the request via following code:

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entityLoginReq, LoginResponse.class);
```

This is the error message i got

```
ERROR 1 --- [nio-8088-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context 
with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request
for "http://abc.xyz:12345/auth/login": Host is unreachable (Host unreachable); nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable (Host unreachable)] with root cause  

java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Host is unreachable (Host unreachable)...
```

But when i try to check accessibility to the host via following command on CLI, i do not have any error message

```
nc -vvw2 abc.xyz 12345
Connection to abc.xyz 12345 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

What do i need to do to overcome the problem i got?

Comment: Are you testing it in the same environment where you are running the java application? May be that there is a docker image running the image and you tested the connectivity in the host machine?

Comment: i test it in kubernetes, so yes, docker container tries to make a REST call to "abc.xyz:12345". Also yes, i tried "nc" command in kubernetes. This is the mistake i made. Thank you for that. I can ping "abc.xyz" in container but when i run "nc -vvw2 abc.xyz 12345" in container, the output is "abc.xyz (100.132.6.24:12345) open" which means that it can not reach to the address. What do i need to do?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO i figured it out. you saved my day, thank you. with all my respects...